# How do I set security.inter.broker.protocol when I have two Kafka brokers with different protocols?

Tags: apache-kafka

I have two kafka brokers, kafka-0 using SSL and kafka-1 using PLAINTEXT (deployed using Docker images).

I need to set security.inter.broker.protocol so that kafka-0 and kafka-1 can talk to each other. When I set it to PLAINTEXT for both brokers, kafka-0 gives the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: security.inter.broker.protocol must be a protocol in the configured set of advertised.listeners. The valid options based on currently configured protocols are Set(SSL)
```

The advertised listener for hafka-0 is

```
advertised.listeners = SSL://IP_ADDRESS:9092
```

Meanwhile if I set the protocol to SSL for both brokers, kafka-1 complains:

```
Error when handling request {topics=[__consumer_offsets]} (kafka.server.KafkaApis) kafka.common.BrokerEndPointNotAvailableException: Broker `0` does not support security protocol `PLAINTEXT`
```

What do I need to change in the setup so that the brokers can talk to each other even though they are using different security protocols?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to get this working is, if you make one of the two brokers (or both) speak both protocols. As long as one is configured exclusively for ssl and one exclusively for plaintext they will not be able to connect to each other.

What you can do is add a plaintext listener to the ssl broker:

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9093,SSL://:9092
advertised.listeners = PLAINTEXT://IP_ADDRESS:9093,SSL://IP_ADDRESS:9092
```

And configure the non-SSL broker to connect to 9093 which should work and keeps all clients that currently use ssl to talk to that broker happy.

Since there is probably a reason why one of them only speaks SSL, it might make sense to secure the plaintext port with a firewall rule so that only the second broker can connect.

Comment: Because I am creating the images through Docker, I also need to set the KAFKA_PORT variable. Do you know how I can manage this if the broker needs to have two ports open? Any examples that I can find online only use one port. Thank you!

Comment: Without knowing which Docker image you use I can only guess, but is it perhaps used to define which ports to expose on the container? Have you tried exposing the second port manually?

Comment: It's the Wurstmeister image (https://github.com/wurstmeister/kafka-docker). The image needs to be built through an Ansible build process so I can't expose the ports manually. I can try just adding the port to the "exposed_ports" and "published_ports" Ansible variables and see if that works.

Comment: From a quick look at that image I am not sure whether the KAFKA_PORT variable is ever really used if you set Listeners and Advertised Listeners..Have you tried it without setting KAFKA_PORT? [It defaults to 9092 if its empty](https://github.com/wurstmeister/kafka-docker/blob/4811383155393d5aaa98d9f97c30775d444e2c7e/start-kafka.sh#L3), but the next if statement won't be run if you set listeners or advertised listeners and that's the only place that KAFKA_PORT would be used again. Perhaps try setting it to 9093 so that it points at the plaintext port..

Comment: Why we should have one PLAINTEXT always, why can't we have both internal and advertised ports configured with SASL_SSL? For more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52409390/docker-kafka-2-0-sasl-mechanism-inter-broker-protocol-is-always-gssapi-even-if